# Adding dependency to androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-beta01 causes runtime exception

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation

I need to add a dependency to **androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-beta01** in an app that uses Android navigation and dynamic features. I need the dependency to call `setFragmentResult`, but the app would stop working with an exception of

> "no class definition found"

At runtime. Please help...

**UPDATE**

This is my app build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.kfi.lorikeetmobile"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0b"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        /*javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [
                        "room.incremental":"true",
                        "room.expandProjection":"true"]
            }
        }*/
    }

    //kotlin DSL
//    configurations.all {
//        resolutionStrategy {
//            force("org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.7.1")
//            force("org.antlr:antlr4-tool:4.7.1")
//        }
//    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

// To inline the bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into
// bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. (e.g. navArgs)


    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    /*dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }*/

    kapt { generateStubs = true }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }

    dynamicFeatures = [":jay", ":stock", ":meddler", ':goods', ':flash', ':inventory', ':harry', ':louis', ':avery']
    buildToolsVersion buildToolsVer
    //kotlin DSL
    /*configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force("org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.7.1")
            force("org.antlr:antlr4-tool:4.7.1")
        }
    }*/
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'

    api 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:$desugar_ver"

    api "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    api "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    api "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9"

    //ROOM
    kapt "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    //kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    //implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

    // Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"


    //PAGING
    //implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:$paging_version"

    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"

    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'

    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    implementation project(path: ':avatarLib')
    implementation project(path: ':ScanditCaptureCore')
    implementation project(path: ':ScanditLabelCapture')

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc03"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:$paging_version"

    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-beta01"
}
```

UPDATE 2

If I move the dependency from the Dynamic Feature that actually uses it to the main app (app gradle), the app doesn't start and I get the following exception:

Unable to start activity

> ComponentInfo{it.kfi.lorikeetmobile/it.kfi.lorikeetmobile.ui.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML
> file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

.... I do not understand what to do more

Comment: Please add your build.gradle

Comment: I've added it. Tx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add `implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"` to your dependencies list to work

Comment: No, it should work without it, because the import for setFragmentResult() is
**import androidx.fragment.app.setFragmentResult**

Comment: The ``fragment-ktx`` library does have a dependency on the ``activity`` library though - I'm not sure where they're up to, but the ``1.3.0-alpha08`` changelog (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha08) mentions that it's using an API introduced in ``activity 1.2.0-alpha08``, so you're probably going to need *at least* that version too (probably the current ``1.2.0-beta01`` though - these are all experimental versions, and alphas are especially squirrely)

Comment: @cactustictacs no, the dependency on activity makes no difference.

Comment: @Sarah when I move the dependency in the app gradle instead of the dynamic feature gradle file as it was before the app crashes at startup, I have updated my post with the exception message